# How to stop rounding in a select case of VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a select case in VBA that is used to take a value and do some mathematics from it. It is then supposed to display the solved for value and the original value in two different cells. When I enter a whole number as the input it works perfectly. However, if I enter 1.2 (or some other decimal) it will use 1.2 for the math and give me the correct value for the one output but for the other output (which just displays the original input) it just says 1 (rounded down) instead of 1.2. How do I get it to show 1.2?  Thanks! (And hopefully that made sense...)

Comment: Hard to make a suggestion as to your problem if you don't post any of your code.

Comment: you only need to declare your variable with the correct data type so decimals will not be omitted. `Double` data type supports numeric values with decimals. see my example below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
Sub test()

Dim lng As Long, dbl As Double, itg As Integer

itg = 24.53
lng = 24.53
dbl = 24.53

MsgBox lng & " " & " " & dbl & " " & itg

End Sub
```

if you run this code, it will display a message box with `25 24.53 25`.
Only the variable declared as `Double` will retain the decimal.
So you only need to declare your variable with the correct data type so as not to ommit the decimal.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't have internet to my computer and was just on my phone, that's why I didn't have the code up :).